# Error: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: json, api, flutter, dart, dio

I want to fetch dat form some API and parse its data to model.

MyModel:

```
class SetupIdeaModel {
  String id;
  String userId;
  String typeIdea = "Implemented Idea";
  String category; //Or Industry
  String experienceYear;
  String experienceMonth;
  String ideaHeadline;
  String ideaText;
  Map timeline = {
    "timelineType": "date",
    "details": null,
  };
  List documents = [];
  Map uploadVideo;
  String location;
  String estimatedPeople;
  Map whitePaper;
  bool needServiceProvider = false;
  bool needInvestor = true;
  }
}
```

and I fetch data from the API with the getIdeaList method:
getIdeaList method

```
Future getIdeaList(String token) async {
    Response response = await APIRequest().get(
      myUrl: "$baseUrl/innovator/idea/list",
      token: token,
    );

    //Parsing ideaList to SetupIdeaModel
    ideas = List();
    try {
      (response.data as List).forEach((element) {
        SetupIdeaModel idea = new SetupIdeaModel();
        var months = int.parse(element["industryExperienceInMonth"]);
        var year = (months / 12).floor();
        var remainderMonths = months % 12;
        print("$year year and $remainderMonths months");
        idea.id = element["_id"];
        idea.userId = element["userId"];
        idea.typeIdea = element["ideaType"];
        idea.category = element["industry"];
        idea.experienceYear = year.toString();
        idea.experienceMonth = remainderMonths.toString();
        idea.ideaHeadline = element["headline"];
        idea.ideaText = element["idea"];
        idea.estimatedPeople = element["estimatedPeople"].toString();
        print("Documents ${element["uploadDocuments"]}");
        idea.location = element["targetAudience"];
        idea.documents = element["uploadDocuments"];
        // idea.timeline = element["timeline"];
        // idea.uploadVideo = element["uploadVideo"];
        ideas.add(idea);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error: $e");
    }

    print("ideas $ideas");
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Everything is OK but When I add one of these line:

```
        idea.documents = element["uploadDocuments"];
        idea.timeline = element["timeline"];
        idea.uploadVideo = element["uploadVideo"];
```

I have got the error.
The data comes for the API is like this:

```
[
   {
      "industryExperienceInMonth":30,
      "estimatedPeople":200,
      "needServiceProvider":true,
      "needInvestor":true,
      "_id":5fcc681fc5b4260011810112,
      "userId":5fb6650eacc60d0011910a9b,
      "ideaType":"Implemented Idea",
      "industry":"Technalogy",
      "headline":"IDea headline",
      "idea":"This is aobut your idea",
      "timeline":{
         "timelineType":"date",
         "details":{
            "date":Dec 6,
            2020
         }
      },
      "uploadDocuments":[
         {
            "_id":5fcc6804c5b4260011810110,
            "uriPath":"https"://webfume-onionai.s3.amazonaws.com/guest/public/document/741333-beats_by_dre-wallpaper-1366x768.jpg
         }
      ],
      "uploadVideo":{
         "_id":5fcc681ac5b4260011810111,
         "uriPath":"https"://webfume-onionai.s3.amazonaws.com/guest/public/video/588700-beats_by_dre-wallpaper-1366x768.jpg
      },
      "targetAudience":"heart",
      "__v":0
   }
]
```

I'm using Dio package.
The documents in the model is a list and the uploadDocuments the come form API is a list too. But Why I got this error.

Comment: Maybe keep `SetupIdeaModel idea = new SetupIdeaModel();` outside the `forEach` loop?

Comment: I suspect that this value `element["uploadDocuments"]` coming from the **API** is a `String `and not a `List`.

Comment: Instead of creating manually https://app.quicktype.io/ go to this link and paste the json response select the language as dart. The Model class will create it for you

Comment: I still have this issue as  Prasanna Kumar says element["uploadDocuments"] coming from the API is a String and not a List. I used json.encode to change string to list but I got another error `unexpected character at index 3. [{_id: "id", uriPath"fdsfadf"}]`

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON data has some syntax errors that's why it's not working. All the UIDs and URLs should be in string format and you should Serializing JSON inside model classes. see [also](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#which-json-serialization-method-is-right-for-me)

I have fix some error in your code and did some improvement :

```
Future getIdeaList(String token) async {
  List<SetupIdeaModel> setupIdeaModel = List();
  try {
    Response response = await APIRequest().get(
      myUrl: "$baseUrl/innovator/idea/list",
      token: token,
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List<SetupIdeaModel> apiData = (json.decode(utf8.decode(response.data)) as List)
        .map((data) => new SetupIdeaModel.fromJson(data))
        .toList();
      setupIdeaModel.addAll(apiData);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error: $e");
  }
}
```

This is the model class :

```
class SetupIdeaModel {
  int industryExperienceInMonth;
  int estimatedPeople;
  bool needServiceProvider;
  bool needInvestor;
  String sId;
  String userId;
  String ideaType;
  String industry;
  String headline;
  String idea;
  Timeline timeline;
  List<UploadDocuments> uploadDocuments;
  UploadDocuments uploadVideo;
  String targetAudience;
  int iV;

  SetupIdeaModel(
      {this.industryExperienceInMonth,
      this.estimatedPeople,
      this.needServiceProvider,
      this.needInvestor,
      this.sId,
      this.userId,
      this.ideaType,
      this.industry,
      this.headline,
      this.idea,
      this.timeline,
      this.uploadDocuments,
      this.uploadVideo,
      this.targetAudience,
      this.iV});

  SetupIdeaModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    industryExperienceInMonth = json['industryExperienceInMonth'];
    estimatedPeople = json['estimatedPeople'];
    needServiceProvider = json['needServiceProvider'];
    needInvestor = json['needInvestor'];
    sId = json['_id'];
    userId = json['userId'];
    ideaType = json['ideaType'];
    industry = json['industry'];
    headline = json['headline'];
    idea = json['idea'];
    timeline = json['timeline'] != null
        ? new Timeline.fromJson(json['timeline'])
        : null;
    if (json['uploadDocuments'] != null) {
      uploadDocuments = new List<UploadDocuments>();
      json['uploadDocuments'].forEach((v) {
        uploadDocuments.add(new UploadDocuments.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    uploadVideo = json['uploadVideo'] != null
        ? new UploadDocuments.fromJson(json['uploadVideo'])
        : null;
    targetAudience = json['targetAudience'];
    iV = json['__v'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['industryExperienceInMonth'] = this.industryExperienceInMonth;
    data['estimatedPeople'] = this.estimatedPeople;
    data['needServiceProvider'] = this.needServiceProvider;
    data['needInvestor'] = this.needInvestor;
    data['_id'] = this.sId;
    data['userId'] = this.userId;
    data['ideaType'] = this.ideaType;
    data['industry'] = this.industry;
    data['headline'] = this.headline;
    data['idea'] = this.idea;
    if (this.timeline != null) {
      data['timeline'] = this.timeline.toJson();
    }
    if (this.uploadDocuments != null) {
      data['uploadDocuments'] =
          this.uploadDocuments.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.uploadVideo != null) {
      data['uploadVideo'] = this.uploadVideo.toJson();
    }
    data['targetAudience'] = this.targetAudience;
    data['__v'] = this.iV;
    return data;
  }
}

class Timeline {
  String timelineType;
  Details details;

  Timeline({this.timelineType, this.details});

  Timeline.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    timelineType = json['timelineType'];
    details =
        json['details'] != null ? new Details.fromJson(json['details']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['timelineType'] = this.timelineType;
    if (this.details != null) {
      data['details'] = this.details.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Details {
  String date;

  Details({this.date});

  Details.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    date = json['date'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['date'] = this.date;
    return data;
  }
}

class UploadDocuments {
  String sId;
  String uriPath;

  UploadDocuments({this.sId, this.uriPath});

  UploadDocuments.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    sId = json['_id'];
    uriPath = json['uriPath'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['_id'] = this.sId;
    data['uriPath'] = this.uriPath;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: The getter 'bodyBytes' isn't defined for the type 'Response<dynamic>'.
Try importing the library that defines 'bodyBytes', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'bodyBytes

Comment: Oh it's becouse I used http package. I didn't see that you used Dio package.

Comment: Insted of `response.bodyBytes` you can use `response.data` I think. Try it. I will update the code.